# regex to find words which isn't inside any tags

Tags: regex

I have a string sample:

```
<a href="#location">location</a> <br> word1 :-) <br>
```

I need to split it so I get a location where I can break this string so It won't break tags as well as words so basically I want to find a space character which isn't inside any tag.
I have created a regex to match tags

```
<\w+.*/\w*?>
```

how can I exclude it so space between "`<a href`" doesn't matches.

**Update:**
I need to split this string in 2 without breaking tags and words
i.e

```
<a href="#location">location</a>
```

&

```
<br> word1 :-) <br>
```

Comment: You should use an HTML or XML parser and select all the text nodes under the body tag

Comment: I actually have it as a string in JavaScript which I am preparing to insert into html

Comment: How about creating the element, selecting its child nodes and testing whether they're text nodes then? - might be a little more resource consuming than a regex but I'm not even sure.

Comment: That could be a way but I want it using a regex way if possible

Comment: What output do you want exactly?

Comment: It's possible, it's just not a good idea. I'll post an answer if nobody beats me to it, but be aware that it won't possibly handle every possible case, HTML as a whole being too complex for regular expressions

Comment: @Aaron I understand but thing is this HTML is generated using js and currently only tags included is `<a>` and `<br>` so currently its pretty much safe to use ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
(?:<(\w+).*?(\/(\1))>|<\w+\/?>|\S+)

<(\w+).*?(\/(\1))> will match for tags like <a> ds</a>
<\w+\/?> will match for <br>,</br> etc
\S+ will match for whole word.
```